# List of the connected Serial port C Qt

Tags: c++, qt, serial-port

I am working in a project with QT and i m trying to get the list of the connected ports

Can any one help me please with this? What is a possible API call for this?

Comment: This is probably highly operating-system specific. Which OS are you coding for?

Comment: Disregard my comment. I think Mali's answer already says it all.

Answer (score 1):

You should use [QSerialPort](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtserialport/qtserialport-index.html)

Look at the [enumerator example](http://doc-snapshot.qt-project.org/qt5-stable/qtserialport/enumerator-main-cpp.html) to know how

If you use Qt4, look [here](http://qt-project.org/wiki/QtSerialPort)

Comment: So you use Qt4 ? Please provide useful informations, QSerialPort is provided in Qt5, if you're using Qt4 you must get the source, compile and install it by hand (I can't help you with this under windows). Look at the link I mention.

Comment: The link is dead. Linked answer is not an answer. Downvoted.